Which language has grammatical tone but no lexical tone?
"Having only grammatical tone" seems to be a marginal case of the definition of "tonal language", and it sounds like the tonal system has collapsed a lot (that the lexical tones have disappeared).
The tonal density generally increases with more tone inventory: /H, Ø/ < /H, L/ < /H, M, L/
A grammatical tone can be a (long-distance floating) tone on verbs to distinguish different moods (indicative, interrogative, imperative, subjunctive etc), which sounds like just a step away from the interrogative intonation in eg. English.
A grammatical tone can also be a tone distinguish noun cases, plurals VS singular etc

Somali is perhaps the most widely discussed language with a strongly morphological tone, but with very few lexical minimal pairs.
